# Pulling option chain with IBrokers

Tags: r, quantitative-finance, ibrokers

Like this:
opt<-reqContractDetails(tws,twsOption(local="", expiry="20111021",right="",symbol="UCO"))

This is unusably slow. Is this because of IB? Any suggestions on how to get an option chain returned in less than 10 minutes?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Get a better ISP?

```
> tws <- twsConnect()
> system.time(opt<-reqContractDetails(tws,twsOption(local="", expiry="20111021",right="",symbol="UCO")))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.07    0.00    0.17 
> twsDisconnect(tws)
```

Comment: Ug. My mistake, I posted incomplete code. That just pulls contract details. I have a loop that gets the price for each contract. I will post it later.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is a limit on the rate you can request quotes at. Make sure you check the API limitations in their reference guide. They also provide Quote boosters which you can buy in case you want to increase your rate. As far as I understand this applies to historical data only but it might apply to real time data as well as is your case. If you hit the rate the API will keep returning rate limit error until a certain period of time passes and you are allowed to make requests again.